# Laravel jetsream profile no funciona

Tags: laravel, laravel-8, laravel-jetstream

estoy probando Jetsream en Laravel 8, y funciona el register y el login, pero al momento de clickear en "Profile" me da este error.
Tengo el Laravel Installer 4.0.4, Laravel Framework 8.5.0.

Para instalar crear el proyecto usé los siguientes comandos:
laravel new jetstream --jet
php artisan migrate

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Lo leí pero no encontré nada que me ayude. Utilizo livewire como corresponde en mi caso. ¿Puede ser que el problema sea que utilizo el localhost de xampp en vez de jetstream.test?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, pude arreglarlo...

Lo que hay que hacer es agregar a todos los href del documento navigation-dropdown.blade.php el código {{url()}}

como por ejemplo cambiar:

```
<x-jet-dropdown-link href="/user/profile">
```

a:

```
<x-jet-dropdown-link href="{{url('/user/profile')}}">
```

**Actualización**

Esto sirve para solucionar el primer problema, pero en consecuencia va generando otros y al final se hace interminable. La solución más eficiente es pasarse a Laragon, Valet o Homestead.

Answer (score 1):

En mi caso estaba usando Wamp, lo que hice fue crear el host virtual desde Apache->httpd-vhosts.conf, luego lo agregué tambien a System, etc, hosts y salió andando.

La url quedó http://laravel8.com.devel

Peero, me esta generando inconvenientes para cargar la foto del profile desde el storage.

Comment: Hola, investigue un poco y por lo que entiendo usar servidores como xamp o wamp no es muy conveniente con laravel, por eso es que nos van surgiendo estos errores. Lo mejor que se puede hacer es pasarse a Laragon, Valet o Homestead

Answer (score 0):

Creo que solo basta con configurar nuestro archivo .env

APP_URL=http://192.168.0.100/public

o si tienes configurados tu vhost por ejemplo como "mipagina.puebras" quedaria

APP_URL=http://mipagina.pruebas

Answer (score 0):

Ingresa este comando, asegurase que estas en la carpeta de tu proyecto.

```
php artisan storage:link
```

todos tus problemas se resuelven viendo la documentacion de lo que usas. https://jetstream.laravel.com/2.x/features/profile-management.html